# Tread wear only in front tires

Tags: tires, alignment

I have a car with all four new tires installed at the same time 6 months ago. Three of them are identical and one is different (front right if this matters). Today, I noticed that the front tires have significant tread wear compared to the rear ones. I have checked several articles on diagnosing tread wear, but his type was not one of them. What could be causing this?

Comment: What did you tell the tire shop when they asked you about an alignment to go along with your new tires?

Comment: I'm confused. You had four new tires installed, but three are identical and one isn't....

Comment: I had it this way and that's what the owner has told me.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the vehicle is front wheel drive,  more wear in the front tyres than the rear is normal as the the driving wheels have plenty more torque and stresses placed on them than the rears. 
Avoiding harsh braking and accelerating will extend the life of the tyres.

Answer (score 1):

If the tire tread is worn evenly and you have a front wheel drive car, that's just wear on your drive wheel from acceleration. On some vehicles, one wheel is favored more than the other. If it's that significant, congrats on driving it like you stole it- nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Have you any resource to cite on this claim?

Comment: Under heading "Tires have not been Rotated": https://www.yourmechanic.com/services/one-tire-is-wearing-faster-than-the-others-inspection

Comment: If there isn't a lot of mileage or aggressive driving I would also suspect an alignment issue... But yeah, FWD always wears heavily in front and almost none in back. One more reason I prefer RWD or AWD :)